# Check if a Predicate condition is not met?

Tags: java, predicates

I am printing a list after testing my predicate and I would like to know if there is a way to check if the condition was not met?

Comment: Check `if (!predicate.test(input)) { /* do something */ }`

Comment: How about `predicate.negate().test(input)` ?

Comment: Appreciate the response however this solution did not work.

Answer (score 3):

Update: Here's a [link](https://howtodoinjava.com/java-8/how-to-use-predicate-in-java-8/) that can help.

```
public static Predicate<Employee> isAdultMale() {
        return p -> p.getAge() > 21 && p.getGender().equalsIgnoreCase("M");
    }
```

In the above example, this is a function that returns the predicate if the condition is met. So similarly maybe you can use this, and when nothing is printed, that's how you know your condition wasn't met.

Comment: Appreciate the response however this solution did not work.

Answer (score 1):

since you are working with a list in order to check the predicate, then option 1

```
Predicate<Integer> p = x -> x > 1;
List<Integer> mL = new ArrayList<>();
mL.add(1);
mL.add(2);
mL.add(3);
```

and use `noneMatch` or `anyMatch`

```
System.out.println(mL.stream().anyMatch(p));
System.out.println(mL.stream().noneMatch(p));
```

read the doc so you can get the right interpretation of that result